# In Rails 3, is form_for supposed automatically know when a model's named helpers are overridden?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, resources, routes

In my routes file I have:

```
resources :features, :as => 'featured'
```

However, when I use the following:

```
<% form_for @feature, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| -%>
<%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :f => f } -%>
<p><%= submit_tag "Feature these submissions" -%></p>
<% end -%>
```

I receive this error:

"undefined method `features_path' for #<#:0x00000106228ec0>"

This is my "new" method in the "features_controller":

```
  def new
    @feature = Feature.new
    @submissions = Submission.find(pending_featured_submissions)
  end
```

Before I upgraded to Rails 3, Rails was able to figure out that I was using a custom named helper. Now it seems as though form_for is ignoring the line in my resources file and using features_path, when it should be used featured_path.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, or missing something.

Thanks for looking =)

Comment: you are right the helper should be updated to featured_path.  when exactly is this error being thrown?

Comment: I pasted the full output here: http://pastebin.com/HP2yf5D7. Its being thrown when I navigate to the "new" method in the "features_controller".

Comment: did you restart the rails server after editing routes?

Comment: Yep, restarted numerous times. :x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what its worth I ended up having to specify the url in the form builder.

```
<% form_for @feature, :url => featured_index_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using submit_tag. If you used the form object to submit then your path will be as defined in the form_for so instead of

```
<% form_for @feature, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| -%>
  <%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :f => f } -%>
  <p><%= submit_tag "Feature these submissions" -%></p>
<% end -%>
```

you should use

```
<%= form_for @feature, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| -%> //Note the = sign
  <%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :f => f } -%>
  <p><%= f.submit "Feature these submissions" -%></p>
<% end -%>
```

Note that because you are in Rails 3 not Rails 2, you should use the = symbol in your form declaration